# Options to use different param

Tags: powershell

I'm looking for a way to to have a choice of a list or a single computername in a foreach loop.

If the user enters in a single computername I want the script to execute for that one computername 
but if that user wants to use a path to a list of computers how could I replace $computername with the path that user wants?

```
function Get-OSInfo {
[CmdletBinding()]
param (
    #[Parameter(ValueFromPipeline=$True,
    #           ValueFromPipelineByPropertyName=$True)]
    [string]$computername,

    [string]$errorlog = 'c:\errors.txt',

    [switch]$logerrors
)


PROCESS {
    foreach ($computer in $computername) {
        Try {
            $os = Get-WmiObject -EA Stop –Class Win32_OperatingSystem –ComputerName $computer 
            $cs = Get-WmiObject -EA Stop –Class Win32_ComputerSystem –ComputerName $computer 
            $bios = Get-WmiObject -EA Stop –Class Win32_BIOS –ComputerName $computer
            $cpu = Get-WmiObject -EA Stop -class Win32_processor -ComputerName $computer 
            $props = @{'ComputerName'=$computer;
                       'OSVersion'=$os.version;
                       'SPVersion'=$os.servicepackmajorversion;
                       'OSBuild'=$os.buildnumber;
                       'OSArchitecture'=$os.osarchitecture;
                       'Manufacturer'=$cs.manufacturer;
                       'Model'=$cs.model;
                       'BIOSSerial'=$bios.serialnumber
                       'CPU Count'=$CPU.Count
                       'Memory'= [Math]::round(($cs.TotalPhysicalMemory/1gb),2) 
                       'CPU Speed'= $CPU.MaxClockSpeed[0]}

            $obj = New-Object -TypeName PSOBject -Property $props
            $obj.PSObject.TypeNames.Insert(0,'Get-OS.OSInfo')
            #Write-Output $obj
            $obj | Export-Csv c:\test4.csv -Append

        } Catch {
            if ($logerrors) {
                $computer | Out-File $errorlog -append
            }
            Write-Warning "$computer failed"
        }

    }


}
```

}

Comment: I dont really want to create two different scripts that both do the same things except one you can use a single computername and the other you can use a list of computer names

Comment: I tried the script in your deleted question and once I disabled the try catch I saw that writing to the root of C:\ `$obj | Export-Csv c:\test4.csv -Append` was the problem. (same with $errorlog)

Answer (score 2):

Change the type of the `$ComputerName` parameter to a string *array* instead of just a single string:

```
param(
    [string[]]$ComputerName,

    [string]$errorlog = 'c:\errors.txt',

    [switch]$logerrors
)
```

Notice the `[]` after the type name, this denotes an array of strings, rather than a single string.

Now you can do:

```
PS C:\> $computers = Get-Content C:\computers.txt
PS C:\> Get-OSInfo -ComputerName $computers
```

---

If you'd like to be able to specify a path to a file containing the target computers as the argument to the function, you can use multiple parameter sets:

```
[CmdletBinding(DefaultParameterSetName='ByName')]
param(
    [Parameter(ParameterSetName='ByName',ValueFromPipeline)]
    [string[]]$ComputerName,

    [Parameter(ParameterSetName='ByFile')]
    [string]$InputFile
)

begin {
    if($PSCmdlet.ParameterSetName -eq 'ByFile'){
        try{
            $ComputerName = Get-Content -LiteralPath $InputFile
        }
        catch{
            throw 
            return
        }
    }
}

process {
    foreach($Computer in $ComputerName){
        # Work with $Computer here...
    }
}
```

Comment: but will that allow me to use c:\computers.txt

Comment: My idea is the user can use get-osinfo -computername computer01
Or
get-osinfo -computername c:\computers.txt

Comment: `Get-OSInfo -ComputerName (Get-Content C:\computers.txt)`? Or, if you add the `ValueFromPipeline` attribute flag, you can do `Get-Content C:\computers.txt |Get-OSInfo`

Comment: Is that the only way

Comment: Add logic in your `BEGIN{}` scriptblock to run `Test-Path` on `$Computer` and if it is true, read that file and use it as the list.

Comment: Per the above code: `Get-OSInfo -InputFile 'c:\Computers.txt'`

Comment: @TheMadTechnician I'd prefer distinct parameter( set)s, might clash with local relative path names otherwise